# split vilon plot with overly crude and adjusted estimates from linear regression

Tags: r, statistics

I want to create a split vilon plot for comparing distance and age and overly crude and adjusted estimates from linear regression on it. my outcome variable lung function. any help would be really appreciated

```
structure(list(id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 13L,
```

14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 31L, 32L,
33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 51L,
52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L
), age = c("child", "child", "adult", "child", "adult", "adult",
"adult", "child", "child", "adult", "child", "adult", "adult",
"adult", "child", "child", "adult", "child", "adult", "adult",
"adult", "child", "child", "adult", "child", "adult", "adult",
"adult", "child", "child", "adult", "child", "adult", "adult",
"adult", "child", "child", "adult", "child", "adult", "adult",
"adult", "child", "child", "adult", "child", "adult", "adult",
"adult"), sex = c("M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M",
"M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M",
"M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F",
"F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M",
"M"), distance = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a",
"a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a",
"a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b",
"b", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b",
"b"), edu = c("x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "x", "x", "x",
"y", "y", "y", "z", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "x", "x",
"x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "x",
"x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z"
), lungfunction = c(45L, 23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 23L, 25L,
45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L,
70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 23L,
69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 25L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 25L,
45L), no2 = c(40L, 70L, 50L, 60L, 30L, 25L, 80L, 70L, 50L, 60L,
30L, 25L, 80L, 89L, 50L, 60L, 30L, 25L, 80L, 89L, 10L, 60L, 30L,
25L, 80L, 89L, 10L, 40L, 30L, 25L, 80L, 89L, 10L, 40L, 70L, 25L,
80L, 89L, 10L, 40L, 70L, 50L, 80L, 89L, 10L, 40L, 70L, 50L, 60L
), pm25 = c(15L, 20L, 36L, 48L, 25L, 36L, 28L, 20L, 36L, 48L,
25L, 36L, 28L, 15L, 36L, 48L, 25L, 36L, 28L, 15L, 25L, 48L, 25L,
36L, 28L, 15L, 25L, 15L, 25L, 36L, 28L, 15L, 25L, 15L, 20L, 36L,
28L, 15L, 25L, 15L, 20L, 36L, 28L, 15L, 25L, 15L, 20L, 36L, 48L
)), row.names = c(NA, -49L), class = "data.frame")

[image]

crude <- lm(lungfunction~distance,
data = publication_dummytable2)
summary(crude)

adjusted <- lm(lungfunction~distance+age+edu+no2+pm25,
data = publication_dummytable2)
summary(adjusted)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear in the question of what columns belong to crude and adjusted values. Here is something using no2 and pm25:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggh4x)
library(see)

data <- structure(list(id = c(
  1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 13L,
  14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 31L, 32L,
  33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 51L,
  52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L
), age = c(
  "a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "b",
  "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a",
  "b", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a",
  "a", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b"
), sex = c(
  "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M",
  "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M",
  "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F",
  "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M"
), distance = c(
  "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a",
  "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a",
  "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b",
  "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b",
  "b"
), edu = c(
  "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "x", "x", "x",
  "y", "y", "y", "z", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "x", "x",
  "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "x",
  "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z"
), lungfunction = c(
  45L, 23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 23L, 25L,
  45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L,
  70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 23L,
  69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 25L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 25L,
  45L
), no2 = c(
  40L, 70L, 50L, 60L, 30L, 25L, 80L, 70L, 50L, 60L,
  30L, 25L, 80L, 89L, 50L, 60L, 30L, 25L, 80L, 89L, 10L, 60L, 30L,
  25L, 80L, 89L, 10L, 40L, 30L, 25L, 80L, 89L, 10L, 40L, 70L, 25L,
  80L, 89L, 10L, 40L, 70L, 50L, 80L, 89L, 10L, 40L, 70L, 50L, 60L
), pm25 = c(
  15L, 20L, 36L, 48L, 25L, 36L, 28L, 20L, 36L, 48L,
  25L, 36L, 28L, 15L, 36L, 48L, 25L, 36L, 28L, 15L, 25L, 48L, 25L,
  36L, 28L, 15L, 25L, 15L, 25L, 36L, 28L, 15L, 25L, 15L, 20L, 36L,
  28L, 15L, 25L, 15L, 20L, 36L, 28L, 15L, 25L, 15L, 20L, 36L, 48L
)), row.names = c(NA, -49L), class = "data.frame")

data %>%
  mutate(age = age %>% recode("a" = "Adults", "b" = "Children")) %>%
  pivot_longer(c(no2, pm25)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, lungfunction, fill = distance)) +
  geom_violinhalf(data = ~ .x %>% filter(distance == "a"), flip = TRUE) +
  geom_violinhalf(data = ~ .x %>% filter(distance == "b")) +
  facet_nested(~ age + sex)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: many thanks for your reply and i have revised the  question adding info about crude and adjusted model.

Comment: It is not specified what `publication_dummytable2` is

Comment: @ danloo,  publication_dummytable2 is data frame (given above) name

Comment: What do you mean with estimates? Predictions on the same dataset as being used for training?

Comment: i mean B coefficient and 95% CI from regression output

Comment: you can not draw beta coefficients estimates as violin plots, because it is not a distribution. You also do not have estimates of children in the crude model, so you can not plot all combinations

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243613/discussion-between-skpak-and-danlooo).